# Cuda OpenCV cvtColor call doesnt convert image to different format

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following code:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(1080, 1920, CV_8UC2, imagedata);
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_image;
gpu_image.upload(image);

cv::cuda::GpuMat bgr_image;
bgr_image.create(1080, 1980, CV_8UC3);

try
{
    cv::cuda::cvtColor(gpu_image, bgr_image, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY);
}
catch (...)
{
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
}
```

The error I get printed out is ERROR: no error.

I dont understand why its throwing with an error message of no error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I also tried it without the create through examples that I have seen online, but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want convert? If you get frame with CUDA from jpeg or h.264 than it has not 3-planes format like YUV420, it is 2-planes format NV12. It's your case? Then use nppiNV12ToBGR_709HDTV_8u_P2C3R function from cuda sdk.

OpenCV has not a good representation for multiplane formats. And cuda module for color conversion can't understand your format: [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/cudaimgproc/src/color.cpp#L2067).

Comment: The current output is not JPEG compressed or H264, its a YUV422 image.  The following code on the CPU works without a problem: cv::cvtColor(image, outimg, CV_YUV2BGR_UYVY);

Comment: And my answer doesn't changing - use nppi functions, OpenCV can't convert your image: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/cudaimgproc/src/color.cpp#L2067